# flowplayer and https

Tags: security, https, flowplayer

I use flowplayer on my site. The problem is that after setting of HTTPS I got warning about insecure content on the page with video player. Is there any way to remove this warning?

Comment: Yes: make sure all of the content is requested via HTTPS.

Comment: @Gumbo Thank you. When I set parameters of flowplayer (path to flash player and path to video) I wrote "http" instead of "https".